# Json parsing in Swift 3.0

Tags: swift3

This is my code for Jason parsing in Swift:

```
 static func POST(url: String, parameters: NSDictionary, completionBlock: @escaping CompletionBlock){

        let todoEndpoint: String = Webservices.Base_Url.appending(url)

        guard let url = NSURL(string: todoEndpoint) else {
            print("Error: cannot create URL")
            return
        }
         var request = URLRequest(url: url as URL)

        //var request = URLRequest(url: NSURL(string: todosEndpoint)! as URL)
        let session = URLSession.shared
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        var err: NSError?
        let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters)

        request.httpBody = jsonData
        request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8 ", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
            guard error == nil else {
                                print("error calling POST on /todos/1")
                                print(error)
                                return
                            }


            // make sure we got data
            guard let dataTemp = data else {
                print("Error: did not receive data")
                return
            }

            // parse the result as JSON, since that's what the API provides
            do {
                      guard let todo = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dataTemp, options: []) as? [String: AnyObject] else {
                        print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
                        return
                }

                // now we have the todo, let's just print it to prove we can access it
                print("The todo is: " , todo)

                // the todo object is a dictionary
                // so we just access the title using the "title" key
                // so check for a title and print it if we have one

            } catch  {
                print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
                return
            }


                        })

        task.resume()

}
```

I got while jason parsing:

> error expression produced error: error: Execution was interrupted,
>   reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0). The process has been
>   returned to the state before expression evaluation.

What's wrong?

Comment: are you able to identify the line at which it is crashing?

Comment: most likely jsonData is nil